# Stackedbars chart overlap in c3js while using timeseries

Tags: c3.js

I am facing an  issue of overlaping in c3js while using type as timeseries

[OUTPUT screenshot of Below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOdI1.png)

As shown in above image below i add code also for you reference

```
      var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        //x : 'indicator',
         xFormat: '%Y%m%d',
         json: [
            { 'indicator': '20160101', 'total': 100 ,'total2': 130 ,'total3': 10 },
            { 'indicator': '20160211', 'total': 200,'total2': 136 ,'total3': 50 },
            { 'indicator': '20150518', 'total': 300,'total2': 230 ,'total3': 60 },
             { 'indicator': '20160111', 'total': 100 ,'total2': 130 ,'total3': 10 },
            { 'indicator': '20161212', 'total': 200,'total2': 136 ,'total3': 50 },
            { 'indicator': '20160528', 'total': 300,'total2': 230 ,'total3': 60 },
             { 'indicator': '20141101', 'total': 100 ,'total2': 130 ,'total3': 10 },
            { 'indicator': '20161211', 'total': 200,'total2': 136 ,'total3': 50 },
            { 'indicator': '20160418', 'total': 300,'total2': 230 ,'total3': 60 }
        ],
        groups: [
            ['total','total2','total3']
        ],
        keys: {
            x: 'indicator',
            value: ['total','total2','total3']
        },
         type: 'bar',
         order: 'asc'
    },
     zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    axis: {
            x: {
           // type: 'category', 
           type : 'timeseries',
               tick: {
                fit: true,
                outer: false,
            // format: function (x) {
                  //  if (x.getDate() === 1) {
                  //      return x.toLocaleDateString();
                  //  }
                  //     }
                format: function (x) { return x.getFullYear(); }
        }
    }
    },
     bar: {
        width: {

            // 6 - items in dataset part of bar width calcuation
            // 28 - items that should have been considered in dataset # of
            //      months between start and end
            // 0.6 - the default bar.with.ratio
           // ratio: 6 / 28 * 0.6
           ratio:0.5
        }
    }
});
```

Can you please help on this?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The bars will overlap, two of your data points are only 1 day apart on a domain that covers over 2 years. To stop these 2 overlapping you'd need the width to be 1px on a 800px wide display of the chart.

The alternatives are:
1) Make it a line chart (but the axes labels still overlap) - simplest
2) Make it a category chart not a time series chart. You lose the sense of distance between the dates, but that's what's causing your problems in the first  place

You'll need to sort your data first, i can't see a c3 command to sort categories

```
  var data = [
        { 'indicator': '20160101', 'total': 100 ,'total2': 130 ,'total3': 10 },
        { 'indicator': '20160211', 'total': 200,'total2': 136 ,'total3': 50 },
        { 'indicator': '20150518', 'total': 300,'total2': 230 ,'total3': 60 },
         { 'indicator': '20160111', 'total': 100 ,'total2': 130 ,'total3': 10 },
        { 'indicator': '20161212', 'total': 200,'total2': 136 ,'total3': 50 },
        { 'indicator': '20160528', 'total': 300,'total2': 230 ,'total3': 60 },
         { 'indicator': '20141101', 'total': 100 ,'total2': 130 ,'total3': 10 },
        { 'indicator': '20161211', 'total': 200,'total2': 136 ,'total3': 50 },
        { 'indicator': '20160418', 'total': 300,'total2': 230 ,'total3': 60 }
    ];
    data.sort (function(a,b) {
        if (a.indicator  > b.indicator) return 1;
        if (a.indicator < b.indicator) return -1;
        return 0;
    })
```

so json becomes `json: data` and later on in the chart declaration you use:

```
    axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category', 
                tick: {
                    // can change the formatting at this point
                    format: function(x) { return this.api.categories()[x]; }
                }
        }
    },
     bar: {
        width: {
           ratio:0.8
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mgraham...your answer  give a bit forword step in my work